# Golang, function pointer to function with value receiver, does not call that function with the changed receiver, when called for the second time

Tags: go, function-pointers, receiver

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type vector struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (u vector) add(v vector) vector {
    fmt.Println("received: ", u)
    u.x += v.x
    u.y += v.y
    return u
}

func main() {
    vecA := vector{x: 5, y: 10}
    vecB := vector{x: 6, y: 7}

    fp := vecA.add // 1

    vecA = fp(vecB)   // 2
    fmt.Println(vecA)

    vecA = fp(vecB)   // 3
    fmt.Println(vecA)
}
/*
Output:
received:  {5 10}
{11 17}
received:  {5 10}
{11 17}
*/
```

At the marking *1*, I declared and initialized `fp` with `add` function, using `vecA` as receiver. At marking *2*, I changed the value of `vecA`. Now at *3*, if we expand the statement: `fp(vecA)`, it becomes: `vecA.add(vecB)`. Now I think it should call `add` function with the 'changed' `vecA`(changed at marking *2*), not the older value of `vecA`(at marking *1*), but it's calling `add` function with the 'old' `vecA`(at mark *1*), which is clear from the output. **Why?**

Though I have found a way to use the new `vecA` like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type vector struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (u *vector) add(v vector) {
    fmt.Println("received: ", *u)
    u.x += v.x
    u.y += v.y
}

func main() {
    vecA := &vector{x: 5, y: 10}
    vecB := vector{x: 6, y: 7}

    fp := vecA.add // 1

    fp(vecB)   // 2
    fmt.Println(*vecA)

    fp(vecB)   // 3
    fmt.Println(*vecA)
}
/*
Output:
received:  {5 10}
{11 17}
received:  {11 17}
{17 24}
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, fp works with the value of vecA so whatever happens to vecA is not reflected in fp after the initial assignment.

In your second example, fp works with the address of vecA. Now you are passing in the value of vecA in the memory location to the add func() so it uses the updated value.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I think it should call add function with the 'changed' vecA

No, this thinking is wrong. fp is and stays bound to the old value.